# Height of React apexchart heatmap is not changing after setting state for it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to resize the height of an "Apexcharts heatmap" depending on the size of data I am getting from the server

I have tried putting the code in componentDidMount() method and the place where the data from the server comes as well, it does not help

in my constructor I have

`this.state{ hmheight=34; }`

then in the method where I get data

`if(datasize){ this.setState({hmheight=90}) }`

then in the render

```
 <ReactApexChart options = { heatOptions }
        series = { this.state.heatData }
        type = "heatmap"
        height = {heatmapHeight} / >
```

noted that series update and view changes but the height does not, while series and height are changed in the same function

I want the height to change on the basis of data coming from the server.

Comment: have you solve this problem. I am setting the height of the apex-chart to 100%  but it's not working.  it has min-height of 430

Comment: I believe I have solved it , but the thing is I dont have the code now

Comment: ok. I have solved it.

Comment: How was this solved? @SandeshSapkota

Comment: Here is how I did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790510/react-apexchart-is-not-taking-its-parent-height-when-setting-height-100/59792904#59792904  @Ravmcgav

Answer (score 0):

it could be because the state variable and value of the height are different. `this.state.hmheight` Vs `height = {heatmapHeight}`

Comment: Thank you , although I have found a solution already :)